# AvPlayer and AirPlay not working quite well

Tags: ios, xamarin, avplayer, apple-tv

I am coding a video player with Xamarin, AVPlayer and `AvPlayerViewController`. My code supports AirPlay and configures AVPlayer according docs but is not working quite well. The following scenario seems to fail:

1. Play a video, send it to Apple TV.
2. Exit playback as it goes on the Apple TV
3. Try to resume playback from the current position. This leads to playback directly starting on the Apple TV but the seek which I do to resume from the last playback position kind of fails. What happens is that `AvPlayerViewController`  UI shows that playback starts from the beginning while the Apple TV is playing back from the resume point. The `AvPlayerViewController` play/pause button is also wrong most of the time and is not reflecting the right play state.

I do the seek so I resume the video like this: wait ( by KVO ) for the avplayer status to become ready to play, seek and then play the video.

Note ... all this works just fine when player is not in airplay mode. Video resumes properly and UI is looking correct.

Code looks like this:

```
avItem = new AVPlayerItem(avAsset);
avPlayer = new AVPlayer(avItem)
{
    AllowsExternalPlayback = true,
    UsesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive = true
};

avPlayerViewController = new AVPlayerViewController()
{
    View =
    {
        ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill,
        AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All,
    },
    UpdatesNowPlayingInfoCenter = false,
    Player = avPlayer
};

initialPlaybackTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(bookmarkTime);

AddChildViewController(avPlayerViewController);
View.AddSubview(avPlayerViewController.View);
avPlayerViewController.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);

avItem.AddObserver(this, new NSString("status"), NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial, IntPtr.Zero);

public override async void ObserveValue(NSString keyPath, NSObject ofObject, NSDictionary change, IntPtr context)
{
    if (Equals(ofObject, avItem) && keyPath.Equals((NSString)"status"))
    {
        if (!initialPlaybackTimeSet && (avPlayer.Status == AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay))
        {
            await avPlayer.SeekAsync(CMTime.FromSeconds(initialPlaybackTime.TotalSeconds, avPlayer.CurrentItem.Asset.Duration.TimeScale));

            avPlayer.Play();
            initialPlaybackTimeSet = true;
        }
    }
}
```